# SharePoint site asking username & password , how to avoid?

Tags: sharepoint, anonymous

I create the sharepoint team site. It asking for username & Password . I want to avoid for asking it.Also want to accsess site without uname & pwd from outside (globally).help please

Comment: Lalit - are you ever actually going to accept any of the answers that people have spent there time giving you? Thats why some of your questions are getting down voted and your rep is rapidly vanishing. Spend 10 mins, click on your user name, go back through your questions and *accept* those answers that are correct by clicking on the tick mark.

Comment: Lalit, no offense; but if your knee-jerk reaction to any little problem you run into at work is to login to stackoverflow and ask this community, the least you could do is mark your previous questions as answered.  Either that, or start distributing your hourly wage to us, since you don't seem to be earning it.

Comment: But i don't know steps to accept answers ? how please???

Comment: Appreciate it Lalit, Looks like you have started marking answers for all the question that you have got solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question tag has the answer you need to enable the anonymous access to the SharePoint. Add to it that when you enable anonymous access you can view the site with read-only and you will have to login to the site to make any changes to it.

And steps to enable anonymous access are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904936/sharepoint-forms-authentication-sites) & [here](http://old.markharrison.co.uk/blog/2006/06/moss-2007-enable-anonymous_12.htm).

Answer (score 3):

Add the site to trusted sites, or my intranet sites and set in your IE options to provide the username and password to intranet sites automatically logon with current username and password.

For outside users this will not work, unless they are accessing your site through vpn (which would make them local users tbh)

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible and you don't really want it. If you could do that, any person on the planet could access your site, add and remove users, delete documents, add documents, or modify them. Kids from anywhere could use it as their private playground.